# about scroll in text with column

Tags: flash, builder

sorry for my english is not very well
i am new in flash builder and i have a problem
i make risising a richeditabletext with a big text and i put columns and scroll 
when i move the scroll bar the last column continous to the end

i want to ask how to scroll the "window text" not all the rest text to last column

```
<s:SkinnableContainer       
    width="100%"    
    height="100%">
    <s:Scroller
        width="100%" height="100%" >

        <s:RichEditableText
            backgroundColor="0x900000"
            id='_text'
            color="0x000000"
            width="100%"
            height="100%" 
            minHeight="0" columnWidth="150" renderingMode="cff" >
            <s:textFlow>
                <s:TextFlow >


            Στον Κοινοβουλευτικό Τομέα Εργασίας του ΠαΣοΚ για θέματα Οικονομίας, ο οποίος θα συγκληθεί την ερχόμενη εβδομάδα, θα μετατεθεί το πεδίο της μάχης για τους βουλευτές που έχουν υπογράψει επιστολή - διάβημα προς τον Πρωθυπουργό κ. Γ. Παπανδρέου. Οι δεκαέξι βουλευτές ζητούν να συγκληθούν άμεσα τα όργανα του κόμματος και της Βουλής ώστε να υπάρξει ένας απολογισμός για τον ένα χρόνο εφαρμογής του μνημονίου και παράλληλα να μην κατατεθεί το μεσοπρόθεσμο πρόγραμμα με ένα άρθρο και να μην ψηφιστεί με τη μορφή του κατεπείγοντος.
            Η κίνηση αυτή των κυβερνητικών βουλευτών αιφνιδίασε τους επικεφαλής της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας, παρότι υπήρχαν σημάδια μεγάλης δυσαρέσκειας, από την πλευρά των βουλευτών τόσο για τα διαφαινόμενα μέτρα όσο και για τη διαδικασία που έχει αποφασιστεί να ακολουθηθεί. Έτσι από το πρωί τους ασκήθηκαν ισχυρές πιέσεις για να ξανασκεφτούν τη συγκυρία και να μην προχωρήσουν στην κατάθεση της επιστολής. Συνομιλίες με τους βουλευτές είχαν συνεργάτες του Πρωθυπουργού αλλά και ο γραμματέας της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας κ. Β. Έξαρχος αλλά και οι δύο κοινοβουλευτικοί εκπρόσωποι κ.κ. Χρ. Πρωτόπαπας και Π. Ευθυμίου, ο οποίος επισήμανε ότι ο κ. Παπανδρέου θα συναντηθεί με τον κ. Ζαν Κλοντ Γιούνκερ, ώστε να υπάρξει λύση στην κρίση χρέους της χώρας και δεν είναι σωστό να δοθεί η εντύπωση ότι αμφισβητείται στο εσωτερικό και ότι είναι Πρωθυπουργός υπό αίρεση. Στον Κοινοβουλευτικό Τομέα Εργασίας του ΠαΣοΚ για θέματα Οικονομίας, ο οποίος θα συγκληθεί την ερχόμενη εβδομάδα, θα μετατεθεί το πεδίο της μάχης για τους βουλευτές που έχουν υπογράψει επιστολή - διάβημα προς τον Πρωθυπουργό κ. Γ. Παπανδρέου. Οι δεκαέξι βουλευτές ζητούν να συγκληθούν άμεσα τα όργανα του κόμματος και της Βουλής ώστε να υπάρξει ένας απολογισμός για τον ένα χρόνο εφαρμογής του μνημονίου και παράλληλα να μην κατατεθεί το μεσοπρόθεσμο πρόγραμμα με ένα άρθρο και να μην ψηφιστεί με τη μορφή του κατεπείγοντος.
            Η κίνηση αυτή των κυβερνητικών βουλευτών αιφνιδίασε τους επικεφαλής της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας, παρότι υπήρχαν σημάδια μεγάλης δυσαρέσκειας, από την πλευρά των βουλευτών τόσο για τα διαφαινόμενα μέτρα όσο και για τη διαδικασία που έχει αποφασιστεί να ακολουθηθεί. Έτσι από το πρωί τους ασκήθηκαν ισχυρές πιέσεις για να ξανασκεφτούν τη συγκυρία και να μην προχωρήσουν στην κατάθεση της επιστολής. Συνομιλίες με τους βουλευτές είχαν συνεργάτες του Πρωθυπουργού αλλά και ο γραμματέας της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας κ. Β. Έξαρχος αλλά και οι δύο κοινοβουλευτικοί εκπρόσωποι κ.κ. Χρ. Πρωτόπαπας και Π. Ευθυμίου, ο οποίος επισήμανε ότι ο κ. Παπανδρέου θα συναντηθεί με τον κ. Ζαν Κλοντ Γιούνκερ, ώστε να υπάρξει λύση στην κρίση χρέους της χώρας και δεν είναι σωστό να δοθεί η εντύπωση ότι αμφισβητείται στο εσωτερικό και ότι είναι Πρωθυπουργός υπό αίρεση. Στον Κοινοβουλευτικό Τομέα Εργασίας του ΠαΣοΚ για θέματα Οικονομίας, ο οποίος θα συγκληθεί την ερχόμενη εβδομάδα, θα μετατεθεί το πεδίο της μάχης για τους βουλευτές που έχουν υπογράψει επιστολή - διάβημα προς τον Πρωθυπουργό κ. Γ. Παπανδρέου. Οι δεκαέξι βουλευτές ζητούν να συγκληθούν άμεσα τα όργανα του κόμματος και της Βουλής ώστε να υπάρξει ένας απολογισμός για τον ένα χρόνο εφαρμογής του μνημονίου και παράλληλα να μην κατατεθεί το μεσοπρόθεσμο πρόγραμμα με ένα άρθρο και να μην ψηφιστεί με τη μορφή του κατεπείγοντος.
            Η κίνηση αυτή των κυβερνητικών βουλευτών αιφνιδίασε τους επικεφαλής της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας, παρότι υπήρχαν σημάδια μεγάλης δυσαρέσκειας, από την πλευρά των βουλευτών τόσο για τα διαφαινόμενα μέτρα όσο και για τη διαδικασία που έχει αποφασιστεί να ακολουθηθεί. Έτσι από το πρωί τους ασκήθηκαν ισχυρές πιέσεις για να ξανασκεφτούν τη συγκυρία και να μην προχωρήσουν στην κατάθεση της επιστολής. Συνομιλίες με τους βουλευτές είχαν συνεργάτες του Πρωθυπουργού αλλά και ο γραμματέας της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας κ. Β. Έξαρχος αλλά και οι δύο κοινοβουλευτικοί εκπρόσωποι κ.κ. Χρ. Πρωτόπαπας και Π. Ευθυμίου, ο οποίος επισήμανε ότι ο κ. Παπανδρέου θα συναντηθεί με τον κ. Ζαν Κλοντ Γιούνκερ, ώστε να υπάρξει λύση στην κρίση χρέους της χώρας και δεν είναι σωστό να δοθεί η εντύπωση ότι αμφισβητείται στο εσωτερικό και ότι είναι Πρωθυπουργός υπό αίρεση. Στον Κοινοβουλευτικό Τομέα Εργασίας του ΠαΣοΚ για θέματα Οικονομίας, ο οποίος θα συγκληθεί την ερχόμενη εβδομάδα, θα μετατεθεί το πεδίο της μάχης για τους βουλευτές που έχουν υπογράψει επιστολή - διάβημα προς τον Πρωθυπουργό κ. Γ. Παπανδρέου. Οι δεκαέξι βουλευτές ζητούν να συγκληθούν άμεσα τα όργανα του κόμματος και της Βουλής ώστε να υπάρξει ένας απολογισμός για τον ένα χρόνο εφαρμογής του μνημονίου και παράλληλα να μην κατατεθεί το μεσοπρόθεσμο πρόγραμμα με ένα άρθρο και να μην ψηφιστεί με τη μορφή του κατεπείγοντος.
            Η κίνηση αυτή των κυβερνητικών βουλευτών αιφνιδίασε τους επικεφαλής της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας, παρότι υπήρχαν σημάδια μεγάλης δυσαρέσκειας, από την πλευρά των βουλευτών τόσο για τα διαφαινόμενα μέτρα όσο και για τη διαδικασία που έχει αποφασιστεί να ακολουθηθεί. Έτσι από το πρωί τους ασκήθηκαν ισχυρές πιέσεις για να ξανασκεφτούν τη συγκυρία και να μην προχωρήσουν στην κατάθεση της επιστολής. Συνομιλίες με τους βουλευτές είχαν συνεργάτες του Πρωθυπουργού αλλά και ο γραμματέας της Κοινοβουλευτικής Ομάδας κ. Β. Έξαρχος αλλά και οι δύο κοινοβουλευτικοί εκπρόσωποι κ.κ. Χρ. Πρωτόπαπας και Π. Ευθυμίου, ο οποίος επισήμανε ότι ο κ. Παπανδρέου θα συναντηθεί με τον κ. Ζαν Κλοντ Γιούνκερ, ώστε να υπάρξει λύση στην κρίση χρέους της χώρας και δεν είναι σωστό να δοθεί η εντύπωση ότι αμφισβητείται στο εσωτερικό και ότι είναι Πρωθυπουργός υπό αίρεση. Στον Κοινοβουλευτικό Τομέα Εργασίας του ΠαΣοΚ για θέματα Οικονομίας, ο οποίος θα συγκληθεί την ερχόμενη εβδομάδα, θα μετατεθεί το πεδίο της μάχης για τους βουλευτές που έχουν υπογράψει επιστολή - διάβημα προς τον Πρωθυπουργό κ. Γ. Παπανδρέου. Οι δεκαέξι βουλευτές ζητούν να συγκληθούν άμεσα τα όργανα του κόμματος και της Βουλής ώστε να υπάρξει ένας απολογισμός για τον ένα χρόνο εφαρμογής του μνημονίου και παράλληλα να μην κατατεθεί το μεσοπρόθεσμο πρόγραμμα με ένα άρθρο και να μην ψηφιστεί με τη μορφή του κατεπείγοντος.


                </s:TextFlow>
            </s:textFlow>

        </s:RichEditableText>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```